# Converting certain sections of a string

Tags: python

I have a string called dna_strand that's approximately 91+ characters. I'm supposed to return a string derived from the dna_strand variable where characters in positions 0 to 62 are uppercase, positions 63 to 90 are lowercase, and positions 91 to the end are uppercase.
   How would i do that? I know i have to do something with `lower()` and `upper()` but I don't know how to get specific sections to use it.

Comment: If you Google the phrase "Python string slice", you’ll find tutorials that can explain it much better than we can in an answer here.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [On topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [... the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here.
StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial resource.

Comment: you need to 'slice' your string, eg. for the first example it should be x = dna_strand[0:62].upper()

Comment: I didnt know i could use upper and lower on a slice. Thank you for helping and not giving me useless advice:)

Answer (score 0):

I reckon you've already found the solution on your own, but here's an example using slicing and the lower/upper cases as you suspected:

```
dna_strand = 'cgtctcgcgctgtgtgcggctaggcagaccagtacccactccttatccaaatagtaacatggcgaataaattagaacgggtacccataataaacgcgta'

formatted_dna_strand = dna_strand[:62].upper() + dna_strand[62:90].lower() + dna_strand[90:].upper()

print(formatted_dna_strand)
```

Which results in:

```
"CGTCTCGCGCTGTGTGCGGCTAGGCAGACCAGTACCCACTCCTTATCCAAATAGTAACATGGcgaataaattagaacgggtacccataatAAACGCGTA"
```